# How to find whether an unordered itemset exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am representing itemsets in SQL (SQLite, if relevant). My tables look like this:

ITEMS table:

```
| ItemId | Name    |
| 1      | Ginseng |
| 2      | Honey   |
| 3      | Garlic  |
```

ITEMSETS:

```
| ItemSetId | Name                |
| ...       | ...                 |
| 7         | GinsengHoney        |
| 8         | HoneyGarlicGinseng  |
| 9         | Garlic              |
```

ITEMSETS2ITEMS

```
| ItemsetId | ItemId |
| ...       | ....   |
| 7         | 1      |
| 7         | 2      |
| 8         | 2      |
| 8         | 1      |
| 8         | 3      |
```

As you can see, an Itemset may contain several Items, and this relationship is detailed in the Itemset2Items table.

How can I check whether a new itemset is already in the table, and if so, find its ID?

For instance, I want to check whether "Ginseng, Garlic, Honey" is an existing itemset. The desired answer would be "Yes", because there exists a single ItemsetId which contains *exactly* these three IDs. Note that the set is unordered: a query for "Honey, Garlic, Ginseng" should behave identically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Itemsets is just the names of the sets. Apart from the silly names, I don't see a particular problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are going to have to use dynamic SQL (assuming your parameters are dyamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you start by placing the item sets that you want to check into a table, with one row per item.

The question is now about the overlap of this "proposed" item set to other itemsets.  The following query provides the answer:

```
select itemsetid,
from (select coalesce(ps.itemid, is2i.itemid) as itemid, is2i.itemsetid,
             max(case when ps.itemid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as inProposed,
             max(case when is2i.itemid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as inItemset
      from ProposedSet ps full outer join
           ItemSets2items is2i
           on ps.itemid = is2i.itemid
      group by coalesce(ps.itemid, is2i.itemid), is2i.itemsetid
     ) t
group by itemsetid
having min(inProposed) = 1 and min(inItemSet) = 1
```

This joins all the proposed items with all the itemsets.  It then groups by the items in each item set, giving a flag as to whether the item is in the set.  Finally, it checks that all items in an item set are in both.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to find an `ItemSet` that:

1. contains all the `Item`s in your wanted list
2. doesn't contain any other `Item`s

This example will return the ID of such an itemset if it exists.

**Note:** this solution is for MySQL, but it should work in SQLite once you change `@variable`s into something SQLite understands, e.g. bind variables.

```
-- these are the IDs of the items in the new itemset
-- if you add/remove some, make sure to change the IN clauses below
set @id1 = 1;
set @id2 = 2;

-- this is the count of items listed above
set @cnt = 2;

SELECT S.ItemSetId FROM ItemSets S

INNER JOIN
(SELECT ItemsetId, COUNT(*) as C FROM ItemSets2Items 
WHERE ItemId IN (@id1, @id2)
GROUP BY ItemsetId
 HAVING COUNT(*) = @cnt
) I -- included ingredients
ON I.ItemsetId = S.ItemSetId

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ItemsetId, COUNT(*) as C FROM ItemSets2Items 
WHERE ItemId NOT IN (@id1, @id2)
GROUP BY ItemsetId
) A -- additional ingredients
ON A.ItemsetId = S.ItemSetId

WHERE A.C IS NULL
```

See [fiddle for MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d45d3/24).